# OSX High CPU Usage

Tags: macos, mac, cpu, processor

Are the following CPU usages normal??
From last few days my macbook air is heating too much. And i frequently notice the fan running fast.

Top two process have always use over 70% cpu and it goes to around 125 sometimes.

Any clues??

[image: CPU Usage]

Comment: Have you tried restarting, quitting Chrome, or disabling Chrome plugins? Have you checked Console.app or system.log? (To potentially make this question more searchable, the processes that use the most CPU include `parentalcontrolsd`, `ocspd`, `PepperFlashPlayer (Chrome Plug-In Host)`, `WindowServer`, `Google Chrome Renderer`, `securityd`, `Google Chrome`, and `Google Chrome Helper`.)

Comment: What does it do when you run it as different user, as Admin ?

Answer (score 3):

It's the parental controls.  Mine does this when the controlled account loses focus - ie if you switch users, or the computer sleeps. The solution is to switch off parental controls for the account, then reboot.