# Macbook often goes to max CPU and then hangs there

Tags: mac, performance

My MBP 2015 15" often hangs with the same sequence of events. First the fan starts rushing up to top speed, then the screen gets some lag, then becomes unresponsive, and then the whole thing hangs in this max CPU state indefinitely until powered off (you can't even move the mouse). I'd really like to be able to log what software is running so I can start to troubleshoot. I don't have to be using any app in particular to make it hang, and I can otherwise do CPU intensive work like video editing without problems. Any ideas?

Comment: I've known OpenGL apps to do that. idk how you could interrogate at Console-level, but keeping Activity Monitor open, sorted by CPU usage could be one way. iStat Menus too, with the GPU menu bar active could maybe let you glance at usage as it starts to ramp.

Comment: Show us a picture in activity monitor what the CPU usage is for all tasks. Also, can you measure external temperature of the case when this happens? Warm or cold might be something to correlate with this. Be sure you edit your post so all the details are in the body. The steps for [kernel task](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102653/osx-high-cpu-usage) are different from overheating from hardware from other...

Comment: It's clear to me.  The user doesn't know what to do.  Not all user are tech savvy.  Try Apple's support site.   Suggest you pick what version of macOS you are using and post in the appropriate forum. https://discussions.apple.com/productsitemap.jspa.

Comment: @historystamp I'm sorry you weren't able to answer the question. Why don't you Google me, and then we can work out who's tech savvy?

Comment: @bmike Once the fan starts, it's already too late to load activity monitor - you can get the box up and start the app, but it'll never load. So I thought the next step would be to set up automatic logs, that can be examined post-hoc

Comment: @historystamp enjoy

Comment: @leon I suggest a hardware test. You may be able to find something in the console. https://www.howtogeek.com/356942/how-to-view-the-system-log-on-a-mac/

Comment: create a launch daemon to run.  while :; do top -l3 >>/Users/mac/topperloop; sleep .5; done;  You will need an account to see this post on how to create a daemon: https://medium.com/@fahimhossain_16989/adding-startup-scripts-to-launch-daemon-on-mac-os-x-sierra-10-12-6-7e0318c74de1

Comment: You could try dtrace.  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2124/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003391-CH1-SECDTRACETOOLS Yes, it's out of date, but it's readable.

Comment: do man dtrace and man dtruss;  see https://8thlight.com/blog/colin-jones/2015/11/06/dtrace-even-better-than-strace-for-osx.html

Comment: Have you tried looking at the console log?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue on my MBP 2017 15", using it with external screens and Mojave 10.14.6. Turned out to be a bug with NightShift (documented [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250645982)). Turning off NightShift solved the problem.

Maybe this will also help you.